# how to insert div directly in tag href area shape

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, shapes, area

I wish to know if it is possible to insert following divs

```
<div id="cal1"> [dopbsp id="1"  lang=it]</div>

<div id="cal2"> [dopbsp id="1"  lang=it]</div>

<div id="cal3"> [dopbsp id="1"  lang=it]</div>
```

directly in the tag `href` image map linked by different shape areas as following

```
<area shape="circle" coords="160,59,20" href="#">
<area shape="circle" coords="111,58,20" href="#">
<area shape="circle" coords="60,59,20"  href="#">
```

so that when I click on shape area, for example

```
<area shape="circle" coords="160,59,20" href="#">
```

then correspondent div, for example

```
<div id="cal1"> [dopbsp id="1"  lang=it]</div>
```

is loaded under the map image
Ps: `dopbsp id="1"`  ... is a calendar booking plugin of wordpress

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. `<area>` cannot have any child elements. See the [World-wide Web compendium working draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/area.html) on the area tag or the [Mozilla Developer Network description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) for more information.

The way to do this is to connect a given `<area>` with a given `<div>` via IDs and use JavaScript to show/hide the `<div>` when you click on an `<area>`. Along the lines of:

```
<area shape="circle" coords="160,59,20" href="#id-of-div-1">
<area shape="circle" coords="111,58,20" href="#id-of-div-2">
<area shape="circle" coords="60,59,20"  href="#id-of-div-3">

<div class="divs-to-show-hide">
 <div id="id-of-div-1">some content here</div>
 <div id="id-of-div-2">some content here</div>
 <div id="id-of-div-3">some content here</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('area').on('click',function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this.href).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: Isn't it  `$($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings().hide();`?

Comment: @krlzlx - `$(this).attr('href') === this.href`.....and this answer is also from 2014 so YMMV if using it today