# How to point to a div using area tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, area

I want to write a code such that when I click on a part of image I got jump to some specific divisions but the following code does not work properly.

```
<div> 
  <img id="FMC" src="img/FMC.png" alt="FMC" id="center" 
    style="position:absolute; top: 50%; left: 28%; top:15%; margin-left: -(X/2)px; margin-top: -(Y/2)px; WIDTH:857px; HEIGHT:500px" 
    usemap="#FMCmap"/>
  <map name="FMCmap" id="FMCmap" >
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,400,200" href="#abcd" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('area').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this.href).show().siblings().hide();
      });
    </script>
  </map>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not seen your full code, But I guess the problem is coming from the following code.

```
  $(this.href).show().siblings().hide();
```

Change this to like below

```
  $(this).attr('href').show().siblings().hide();
```

Comment: I tried the correction you suggested but it's still not working.It will be so nice of you if you can find the error I made. By the way the code I used for that is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183492/how-to-insert-div-directly-in-tag-href-area-shape